# javascriptのawaitの後ろに括弧が二重に並んでいる。

Tags: javascript

下記のサイトでこのようなコードを見たのですが、これは即時関数でしょうか？即時関数は無名関数に付けられると聞きました。

[[Python] EelをつかってHTML/CSS/JavaScriptでGUIを構築 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/inoory/items/f431c581332c8d500a3b)

**コード**

```
async function run() {
    let val = await eel.python_function2()();
    console.log(val + " from Python")
}
run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

特別な意味はないです。返された関数を実行したかったから関数呼び出しをおこなっただけかと。

```
let func = eel.python_function2();
let awaitable = func();
let val = await awaitable;
```

Comment: 返信が遅れてすいません。`eel.python_function2()`の戻り値が関数でそれを実行したかったという事ですね。ありがとうございます。